# how to make bootstrap components work with my phone?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[![This is what i get when i view my page via a phone

```html
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
//body part
<?php $this->load->view('navigation'); ?>
<div id='display'>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id='display_show'>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>images/c2b.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="340" height="300">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>images/c2s.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="340" height="300">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="view">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" id='btn_overlay' class="btn btn-warning btn_view"><font size='4px'>C1</font><br />kariakoo</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_view"><font size='4px'>C2</font><br />kariakoo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

][1]][1]

[image]

am getting trouble getting my view via smart phone

Comment: What's being loaded inside <?php $this->load->view('navigation'); ?>  we need to see the HTML and see but not the PHP ?

Comment: I don't see any bootstrap css file attached in your html file

Comment: If it works on pc, It will work on mobile too.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on desktop, it should also work on mobile.

The device isn't pulling down the stylesheet, ensure that your web server has read access to any stylesheets stored locally and that all stylesheets have been placed in the right folders.

**Edit:** it doesn't look like you're pointing to any stylesheets in the head of your HTML page, this may be your problem unless code has been omitted from your question.

Replace site.css with the relative filepath and filename of your CSS file.

```
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```